# Is it true that there will not be 32-bit Ubuntu Server 12.10 ?

Tags: server, 12.10, 32-bit

Is it true that there will not be 32-bit versions of Ubuntu Server anymore? If so, that's really unfortunate.

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep it's true. You can read more here:
http://www.thevarguy.com/2012/08/23/ubuntu-server-plans-to-move-away-from-32-bit-computing/

But it's not a big deal, especially on a Server. It's not like they're completely dumping 32-bit. You can still download Ubuntu 12.04 for 32-bit severs and then you can just update most packages from there. Also, since 12.04 is an LTS you've got at least 3 years of Updates and 7 years of support for it. By then you'll probably have already upgraded your PC/Server to a 64-bit system.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I run my PC on 64-bit, I just asked because I do have a few servers on Ubuntu Server that are 32-bit.

Comment: Well, don't worry about them since they should keep getting updates for awhile even if they don't get any more Major Releases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can still download an ISO for Ubuntu 12.10 Server 32 bit [directly from the release page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/):

> **PC (Intel x86) server install image For almost all PCs.**
>
> > This includes
> >     most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all
> >     computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh
> >     systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all
> >     unsure.